# Laravel: foreign key error

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5

I am getting this error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `offers` add constraint offers_client_id_foreign foreign key (`client_id`) references `clients` (`id`))

[PDOException]
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

Creating table clients

```
Schema::create('clients', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
    ...
});
```

Creating table offers

```
Schema::create('offers', function(Blueprint $table)
{
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
    ...
});

Schema::table('offers', function($table) {
    $table->foreign('client_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('clients');
});
```

Model offer

```
class Offer extends Model {
    /**
     * Relations
     * An offer belongs to client
     */

    public function client() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Client');
    }
}
```

Model client

```
class Client extends Model {
    /**
     * Relations
     * A client can have many offers
     */

    public function offers() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Offer');
    }

}
```

I am creating table clients before table offers.
Any ideas what could be wrong? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Unless I'm reading this wrong I think you answered your own question, you should be creating client table and then offers since offers has a foreign key reference to client.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo. I have changed it.

Comment: Please show the code that create the client table. Double check that id field at client table is unsigned integer.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the **unsigned** of client primary key **id**

```
Schema::create('clients', function(Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    ...
});
```

The **increments** method already means unsigned integer.

Comment: Nope, same error. I don't know what could be wrong. Perhaps the relations?

Answer (score 0):

My apologies, I was looking at my seeding procedure for the order. At the end, I really had offers table created before clients table - in migrations.

This is working now.